# Using ViewModel with a PartialView in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to use a PartialView with a ViewModel but I am getting the error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Regression', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'RegressionVM'.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult _Regression(Regression regression)
        {
            var model = new ViewModels.RegressionVM(regression); 
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

Partial View

```
@model  ViewModels.RegressionVM

    <div>
        <p>Correlation Coefficient : @Model.Regression.CorrelationCoefficient</p> 
    </div>
```

Main View (relevant part)

```
  @Html.Partial("_Regression", SectorAnalysis.evReg)
```

I've checked that the object passed to the partial controller is not null and is of the correct type.
If in the controller I simply take in a type Regression and pass it to the PartialView that works fine but I get errors whenever I use a view model pattern.

Interestingly if I omit the viewmodel from the partial controller as below the error goes away (obviously I change the partial view to accept @model  Regression) :

```
 public ActionResult _Regression(Regression regression)
        { 
            return PartialView(regression);
        }
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: What is the model in the main view (I assume its `@model Regression`)? The error means that `SectorAnalysis.evReg` is `null` and so the `@Html.Partial()` method uses the model in the main view. Its a bit unclear what your doing because you have not given enough information. Where for example are you calling the `_Regression()`?

Comment: What is `SectorAnalysis.evReg`? Is it a static field or part of Model?

Comment: @Stephen I was assuming that the main model view was irrelevant (it is another viewmodel).Regression is actually a class not a method. I checked in the debugger that evReg is of the correct class and not null. I made the question a bit clearer by showing what worked (ie not using a viewmodel in the controller).

Comment: I know `Regression` is a class :). I was referring to `_Regression()` (the controller method)

Comment: Having seen your edit, I assume that `SectorAnalysis.evReg` is typeof `Regression` (and not typeof `RegressionVM` which it needs to be). `@Html.Partial()` does not call a server method and execute the code in the `_Regression()` method - it just renders the partial. If `evReg` is typeof `Regression`, then you need to use `@Html.Action("_Regression", SectorAnalysis.evReg)`

Comment: Thanks, I acutally found creating an instance of the ViewModel in the Html.Partial fixed the problem. @Html.Partial("_Regression", new ViewModels.RegressionVMSectorAnalysis.evReg))

Comment: Then what is the point of the `_Regression()` method? (are you using it somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
 @Html.Partial("_Regression", SectorAnalysis.evReg)
```

to this

```
 @Html.Action("_Regression", "ControllerName", SectorAnalysis.evReg)
```

Rationale:

`Html.Partial` does not call the controller action, it simply attempts to render the partial view with the model that you sent it.  In your case, you are sending a model of type `Regression` to a partial view that is expecting a model type of `ViewModels.RegressionVM`.  By calling `Html.Action()`, you are instructing the razor view engine to execute the action in your controller that takes a `Regression` type object and returns a `ViewModels.RegressionVM` to the partial view.